# Clarity Tree View expand/collapse icon disappears when adding dojo.js to index.html

Tags: angular, svg, dojo, vmware-clarity

We have a working Angular 4 application which uses [Clarity's Tree View](https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.11/tree-view).  We've been very happy with this control and we would like to continue using it.

Recently, we've added another (non-angular) component to the application which requires `dojo.js`.  We're importing `dojo.js` from `index.html` like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/dojo/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

Alas, when this import is added, the expand/collapse arrow/caret image on expandable tree nodes no longer appear.

Comparing the two rendered pages, I've found that the `clr-icon` element in the final DOM no longer contains a nested `svg` element.  The missing `svg` element looks like this (some text replaced with ellipis by me):

```
<clr-icon ...>
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 36 36" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" xmlns="..." xmlns:xlink="..." focusable="false" role="img">
  <title>angle</title>
  <path class="clr-i-outline clr-i-outline-path-1" d="..."></path>
</svg>
</clr-icon>
```

My current hypothesis is that the introduction of `dojo.js` causes a namespace collision which prevents some bit of "insert SVG elements" code from running.

How can the SVG element be restored while continuing to import `dojo.js` from index.html?

Comment: Hi there, we don't recommend an additional framework with clarity. I'm sorry but I'm not familiar with dojo.js, can you expand on what it offers for your application?

Comment: The other component is an advanced data visualization tool.  Dojo is a javascript framework that they use to implement part of their tool.

Comment: Can you point me to where/how Clarity inserts the SVG tags into the DOM?  I may be able to track down the conflict from there...

Comment: Clarity Icons (separate from the UI and Angular packages) lives here: https://github.com/vmware/clarity/tree/master/src/clr-icons 

It creates custom elements for the svg's.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `dojo.js` **NPM** package from here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dojo.

Although I never used `dojo.js` with our `vmware-clarity` solution, we used other `Javascript` libraries like `dimple.js` and `vis.js` in that fashion.

In `package.json`, you add the dependency.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    ...
    "dimple-js": "^2.1.4",
    "vis": "^4.20.1",
    ...
  },
```

This will install the node modules.

Following is an example of how we used `vis.js`.

```
import {Component, Input, OnChanges, OnDestroy, OnInit, Output,EventEmitter, SimpleChanges} from "@angular/core";
import {DataSet, Edge, IdType, Network, Node} from "vis";

@Component({
...
})

export class DemoComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy {

...

    ngOnInit() {
        this.onRefresh();
    }

    onRefresh(){
        ...
        var container = document.getElementById('network');
        var data = {
             nodes: this.nodes,
             edges: this.edges
        };
        var options = {
             width: '1000px',
             height: '450px',
             ...
        };

        this.network = new Network(container, data, options);
        var initPosition = {
            scale : 0.8
        };

        this.network.moveTo(initPosition);
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
         if(...){
              this.onRefresh();
         }
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.